# Get previous week date range php

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime, mktime

I need help getting the "this week" full date range in the following format: Y-m-d

I have successfully been able to get "this month" full date range but not the "this week" full date range.

This is my code for "this month":

```
//Functions for later use
function firstOfMonth() {
    return date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
}

function lastOfMonth() {
    return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
}

//Setup the date_range variables
$date_start = firstOfMonth();
$date_end  = lastOfMonth();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just so you know, your "first of month" code is wrong. If you're in August, it'll give you the range July 8th to August 7th. Use the correct d/m/Y format when doing it that way around.

As for the week, try this:

```
$start_week = strtotime("last monday midnight");
$end_week = strtotime("+1 week",$start_week);

$start_week = date("Y/m/d",$start_week);
$end_week = date("Y/m/d",$end_week);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for last week if its Monday now; if its Tuesday won't last Monday give yesterday?

Comment: ^ Yes. For last week's Monday, you need to do `$thisWeeksMonday = strtotime("last monday midnight"); $lastWeeksMonday = strtotime('-1 week', $thisWeeksMonday);`. Of course, you need to check if today is a Monday as well. Also, there is a typo in the answer.

Comment: @FranVerona Thanks for the edit. I'm kind of amazed that 1) I made those errors and 2) they went unedited for such a long time!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I recently came to this question when I was looking for something like this on Google. Your welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

Layton Everson you are correct.  The correct format I think should be :

```
strtotime('-2  Monday');
```